# WCF Data Service on IIS using Mysql

Tags: asp.net, mysql, wcf, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

I have a Web service that was created as a WFC Dataservice based on a EntityFramework model that is created from a MySQL schema.
When I run the web service in Visual Studio, the Web Service is created and I'm able to retrieve data.
I'm running the tests locally but the Web Service is connected to a remote database (MySQL-net/connector 6.6.4.0). And it's running like a champ.

My problem starts when i publish my Data service to my shared host provider. When i do, i get the following error message:

```
    The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at System.RuntimeFieldHandle.GetValue(RtFieldInfo field, Object instance, 
RuntimeType fieldType, RuntimeType declaringType, Boolean& domainInitialized)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, Boolean     doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
at system.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
at system.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() 
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ForceOSpaceLoadingForKnownEntityTypes()
at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter.get_ObjectContext() at lambda_method(Closure , Object ) 
at System.Data.Services.Providers.DbContextHelper.GetObjectContext(Object o) 
at System.Data.Services.Caching.MetadataCache`1.TryLookup(Type serviceType, Object dataContextInstance) 
at System.Data.Services.Providers.BaseServiceProvider.LoadMetadata() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateMetadataAndQueryProviders(IDataServiceMetadataProvider& metadataProviderInstance, IDataServiceQueryProvider& queryProviderInstance, BaseServiceProvider& builtInProvider, Object& dataSourceInstance) 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.CreateProvider() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest() 
at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessRequestForMessage(Stream messageBody) 
at SyncInvokeProcessRequestForMessage(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) 
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

My Web.Config file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--
      For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
      http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
      -->
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
       <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
      </system.web>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="UgyvediAdatbazisEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ugyvediDbModell.csdl|res://*/ugyvediDbModell.ssdl|res://*/ugyvediDbModell.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=UgyvediAdatbazis.db.10115243.hostedresource.com;user id=UgyvediAdatbazis;password=*******;database=UgyvediAdatbazis&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v11.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
      </entityFramework>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics>
          <messageLogging logMalformedMessages="true"
                          logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                          logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                          logEntireMessage="true"
                          maxMessagesToLog="10000"/>
        </diagnostics>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="Hibajelzes" >
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoAuth">
              <security mode="None">
                <!--<transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>-->
              </security>               
            </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NoAuth">
              <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicAuth">
              <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="UgyvediWebApp.UgyvediDataService" behaviorConfiguration="Hibajelzes">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="NoAuth"
                      contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler">          
            </endpoint>
          </service>
        </services>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">

          <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <!--<add prefix="http://www.omegabridge.com/ugyvediservice/"/>-->
          </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        </serviceHostingEnvironment>
      </system.serviceModel>

      <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
          <add
                name="MySQL Data Provider"
                invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL"
                type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, 
                      Version=6.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, 
                      PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
            />
        </DbProviderFactories>

      </system.data>

      <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"/>
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
      </system.webServer>

    </configuration>
```

I think my problem is with the MySQL connector but i cant figure out what exactly.
The MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entity, and MySQL.Web are referenced and set to Copy Local.
I even tried to use the embedded data service Diagnostics but the wcf trace file only came back with the previously shown stack trace.

Pls. if any lad have any idea how to solve this issue share it with me.

Comment: Did you check if you have deployed the MySql.Data.dll and also ensure that the corresponding section is registered in the web.config of your application.